# Посчитать количество строк в сгрупированном запросе

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
SELECT * FROM `matches` GROUP BY `dota_match_id`
```

Вот таким запросом я получаю поля для вывода, мне нужно посчитать их количество
Пытаюсь получить обычным count()

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `matches` GROUP BY `dota_match_id`
```

Но мне выводить количество сгрупированных полей.

Как такое можно реализовать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   `matches` 
        GROUP  BY `dota_match_id`) AS T
```

Answer (score 3):

Я так понял, вам нужно количество уникальных значений `dota_match_id`, попробуйте:

```
SELECT count(distinct dota_match_id) FROM `matches`
```